# Are there two Task List Views?

Tags: list-view

[image: Task List Image]

I'm getting a little confused about the Task List Views. 
What is the difference between the views with the All Tasks, Calendar, Completed, ect.. and the view for the Items... Task Name, Start Date ect...

Answer (score 1):

The first box represents "All Tasks, Calendar, Completed" are the views created for task list.

The Second box represents columns in you current selected view. for e.g. in you above screenshot All tasks view is selected and below shows the columns which are configured in view settings, now when you select any other view like completed you can have different set of columns to be displayed.

Hope this helps, please upvote or mark it answer if it is clear..

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple views not only two views, and you can also build your custom views based on your requirements,

The main diff between the default views is the way to show this items and the filter and sort and group by setting for each view.

Regarding :

- **All tasks** : to show all list items within the list .
- **Calendar** : to show the tasks based on it's start date and end date as a calendar
- **Completed** : to the show the completed tasks .

if you click also on `...` you will find the additional views like Late tasks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default whenever you create a Tasks list, SharePoint automatically create 7 different views of the list in the background by default. The primary difference among them would be in the view query and view type and certain view fields.

[image]

The description of these views is as below:

1) All Tasks - The default view showing the all the tasks created in the task list without any filtering or sorting. Its a standard view.

2) Late Tasks - It shows all the tasks that are running late. Its sorted first on Due Date and then on Priority. The filter of items is as below. Its a standard view:

[image]

3) Upcoming - It shows all the tasks whose due date is greater than or equal to today. Its a standard view. Filtering is as below:

[image]

4) Completed - Another standard view that shows all the tasks which are completed i.e the %Complete value is 100 %

5) My Tasks - Another standard view which displays the tasks assigned to the current user. Filter is AssignedTo =[ME]

6) Calendar - Its a Calendar view that shows the tasks details in a Calendar format similar to that in a Calendar list.

7) Gantt chart - Its a Gantt chart view which displays list items in a Gantt chart to see a graphical representation of how a team's tasks relate over time